# Deploying static media to a server separate from the main environment

Tags: django, deployment, fabric

I'm having trouble with some changes to a fabric deployment script.  We are switching from using a prone to breakage NFS mount for hosting our static media to using a separate webserver that will host and handle all of our static media.

The goal is that regardless of environment that we're deploying (test, prod, etc) that the upload_static_content command will only run on the static media server.  Right now if we run `fab test upload_static_content` everything works out perfectly.  The static content ends up on the correct server in the correct directory.  However, if we run `fad test deploy` the static content ends up on the test webserver rather than the intended server.

```
def test():
    ...
    env.hosts=testhosts

def prod():
    ...
    env.hosts=prodhosts

def deploy():
    # Do some deployment stuff
    ...
    upload_static_content()
    ...

@hosts([static_server,])
@run_once
def upload_static_content()
    # Upload static content to a different server
    ...
```

Comment: Should it not be something like `fab prod deploy`?

Comment: Not sure what you mean.  For a test environment (staging) deploy we'd execute `fab test deploy` and for a production environment deploy we'd execute `fab prod deploy`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the *execute* function which was introduced in Fabric 1.3? It should honor the @hosts decorator.

```
def deploy():
    # Do some deployment stuff
    ...
    execute(upload_static_content)
```

Here's the documentation:

http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.4.2/usage/execution.html#intelligently-executing-tasks-with-execute

Comment: That's it, this is the part we overlooked.  We haven't needed to use this type of functionality before.